# Making navigation collapse

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is the navigation bar from the Bootstrap website, along with the css. How can I make it collapse when below 768px? I want a justified navigation and tried looking at the navigation that has the collapse function, but not sure where to add it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks, jodmcc

HTML

```
  <!-- The justified navigation menu is meant for single line per list item.
       Multiple lines will require custom code not provided by Bootstrap. -->
  <div class="masthead">
    <h3 class="text-muted">Project name</h3>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav nav-justified">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
   .nav-justified {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.nav-justified > li > a {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #777;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e5e5e5; /* Old browsers */
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left     bottom,     from(#f5f5f5), to(#e5e5e5));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5 0%, #e5e5e5     100%);
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5 0%, #e5e5e5     100%);
  background-image:         linear-gradient(to bottom, #f5f5f5     0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(         startColorstr='#f5f5f5', endColorstr='#e5e5e5',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
  background-repeat: repeat-x; /* Repeat the gradient */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
    }
    .nav-justified > .active > a,
    .nav-justified > .active > a:hover,
    .nav-justified > .active > a:focus {
      background-color: #ddd;
      background-image: none;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
          box-shadow: inset 0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    }
    .nav-justified > li:first-child > a {
      border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    }
    .nav-justified > li:last-child > a {
      border-bottom: 0;
      border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap's `.hidden-xs` CSS class on elements that should be hidden below 768px. Conversely, you can make elements appear only above 768px or higher by using `.visible-xs-block`, `.visible-xs-inline`, or `.visible-xs-inline-block` (depending on your display style).

For instance, you could try:

```
<div class="hidden-xs">
    Standard menu code, visible at 768px or above
</div>
<div class="visible-xs-block">
    Collapsed menu code, only visible below 768px
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should have given a little more information. I would like to have the "hamburger" menu button show below 768px and when clicked will expand showing menu items.